# IIS10 not saving (all) configuration details to site's web.config

Tags: windows, iis, web.config

The `web.config` on a fresh IIS install contains the sites configuration details, except for `<ipSecurity>`. However, the (site local) IP restrictions work fine and can be edited through the IIS manager console.

In my `web.config` I do see things like

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
...
```

but I do not see any IP security rules, that I add tthrough the IIS manager (like feature settings or allow/forbidden addresses). I expected to find them here, just like any other setting.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/deep-dive-into-iis-configuration-with-iis-7-and-iis-8#configuration-levels Read from "Security: Occasionally, machine administrators want to be able to control the configuration everywhere on the server".

Answer (score 4):

The `web.config` file in the root of your web site is not the only file where configuration is/can be stored in IIS.

Further web.config file can exist in sub-folders of your site.

Many settings are by default not supposed to be saved in the site's web.config and therefor be edited by a normal user. These settings are stored in a central file which also has the configuration for the server level.

the file is at:

```
 C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Config\ApplicationHost.config
```

IP security rules are by default stored in `ApplicationHost.config`

If you open IIS Manager and select the server level, and then under Management click on the `Feature Delegation` icon you can see a list of features.

`IP Address and Domain Restrictions` are listed as `Read Only` which means they can only bo stored in the `ApplicationHost.config` file. If you change this to `Read/Write` they may be stored in your site's `web.config` file as well.

If you are going to use IIS a lot, make yourself familiar with the hierarchical configuration system in IIS.